# How can I query this on MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this on my database example:

```
tA------tB
lewbr - blabla1
lewbr - blabla2
lewbr - blabla3
blabla1 - lewbr
blabla2 - lewbr
blabla3 - lewbr
```

What do I need to do on `SELECT` to get all texts from `lewbr`?

Example: `List of LewBr: blbla1, blabla2, blabla3`

I have this on my PHP in a software game:

```
public function getAllFriends($oi1) {
            $a = $this->plugin->provider->db->query("SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE tA='$oi1'");
            $b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a);
            return $b;
    }
```

EVENT

```
                    $msg = null;
                    foreach($this->getAllFriends($player) as $friend => $p) {

                        if($friend == 'p2') {
                            $msg .= "$p, ";
                        }
                    } 
                    $sender->sendMessage("HI: $msg");
                    return;
```

but it only returns 1 player of the list.. like

```
List of LewBr: blabla1,
```

Comment: sorry bad english.

Comment: Hi, you misunderstood mysqli_fetch_assoc.  This function will return 1 line of results from the query execution.  Not the full set.  So your foreach in the event loops on 1 line, so 1 result.  Return $a in your function and loop on that.

Comment: I had tested that what you say and doesn't works too.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the values on the same row in a list with comma separated values you could use group_concat

```
"SELECT group_concat(tb)  as my_amigos
 FROM amigos WHERE tA='$oi1'
 group by tA"
```

you can easily obutain the list without the foreach  ... just accessing the my_amigos column eg:

```
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a);
  var_dump($row['my_amigos']);
```

if you don't want comma as separator  you could use space eg:

```
"SELECT group_concat(tb SEPARATOR ' ' )  as my_amigos
 FROM amigos WHERE tA='$oi1'
 group by tA"
```

Comment: what what do i do on the event?

Comment: just keep it so?

Comment: answer  updated  with a suggestion  hope is clear ..

Comment: i don't know why but it return's NULL on var_dump

Comment: check for the correct alias  ..

Comment: i still get NULL

Comment: I have tested all you say :/

Comment: there was wrong  single quotes after $oi1 .. and grup by  ...answer updated

Comment: Work's now! thank you.

Comment: It has an way to get whitout ,?

Comment: explain better  .. without what ? .... there was a last  single quote at  the end ...  removed

Comment: like when i run this i receive the list so: blabla1, blabla2, etc... but i need to get blabla1\nblabla2\blabla3 or whitout " , "

Comment: answer  update   ...  you can change the separator

Comment: Nice, thank you. And last question, it has an way to set event on this query? Example: i want to return if he is anything example: Online then return = blabla1 - Online blabla2 - Offline i have tested this but don't work: look the question has been edited on top

Comment: your question in  comment is not clear  to me  .. could be  is not properly formatted  or well described .. you could try post a new question with a data sample and the expected  result  ..eventually comment me the link for tyhe new question  ..

Comment: and don't change an answer  that you have alredy a valid  answer .. is not fair and the question could became incoherent ..

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, so i need to create a new post and back this post?

Comment: should be better ..    and comment me the link .. for he new question when you have done ..

Comment: I have reached questions.. :/

Comment: what do you mean ?   .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003577/how-to-do-events-on-mysql-scaisedge